# Parsing JSON using AFNetworking 2.0 exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

i have an issue handling the JSON parsed data using AFNetworking.

here's my code:

```
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"strEmail": _logInEmail.text, @"strPassword":_logInPassword.text};
        [manager POST:@"http://carefid.com/api/user/login.php" parameters:parameters success:^

          (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


//NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
              NSString *str = responseObject[@"error"];
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", str);
            UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootController"];
            [self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

when im trying to log the value i get this error:

```
2014-07-15 14:39:08.438 carefid[7858:60b] -[_NSInlineData objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1094c67a0
2014-07-15 14:39:08.441 carefid[7858:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1094c67a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101d48495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001019c399e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101dd965d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101d39d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101d39938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   carefid                             0x000000010001f14f __34-[ViewController existingUserBtn:]_block_invoke + 95
    6   carefid                             0x0000000100015648 __64-[AFHTTPRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke46 + 40
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102669851 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010267c72d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010266c3fc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 354
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101da6289 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101cf3854 __CFRunLoopRun + 1764
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101cf2d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001040bef04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000100570e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    15  carefid                             0x0000000100049183 main + 115
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001028cd5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What could cause this problem? is the responseObject is an dictionary?
if my code is wrong, how should I handle this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are setting the response parser to `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` and not `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. So the response is never parsed a JSON.

So change

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

to

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

As mentioned in you comment the server is delivering the content `text/html`, if possible the server should say the content is op type `application/json`, `text/json` or `text/javascript`.

If it is not possible to change the servers content type you can tell the `AFJSONResponseSerializer` to accept `text/html` like:

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *jsonReponseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; 
// This will make the AFJSONResponseSerializer accept any content type
jsonReponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;
manager.responseSerializer = jsonReponseSerializer;
```

Comment: 2014-07-15 15:26:19.765 carefid[8036:60b] Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x10d924d10 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x10d929b60>

now i get this error..

Comment: Your server is sending the JSON content to the app as `text/html` which is incorrect and if possible should be changed on the server to `application/json`, `text/json` or `text/javascript`

Comment: there is any way that i can handle it from my side?

Comment: Well if you server is now done, aka sending some 500 server error page the JSON parse will try and parse it. Not really a problem but just not needed and could give some difficulties later on.

Comment: It's worth noting that the default `responseSerializer` on `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is an instance of `AFJSONResponseSerializer`

Comment: @OshriALM  I am having the same issue right now.Do someone found the solution for the issue???

I am curious what causes unrecognized selector response  for the Http response..